NEF files can not open correctly on windows
I have a desperate situation. I bought my Nikon Z8 and there are several errors.
I have a Windows 10 and when I try to open my NEF files after 3sec they turned with thin lines like a rainbow.
I compressed the RAW on the camera to lossless and these pictures does open but after seconds the contrast and the highlights changes.
Is this a problem with my camera settings or it’s the computer ?
Thank you for your help!

What software application are you using on your computer to open the NEF files?

"after seconds the contrast and the highlights changes": when the program opens the RAW image data, it first shows you an embedded JPEG "thumbnail" (quotes because this can be almost full size), while it decodes the raw data. When it's done its shows you the raw data, and its default interpretation of it can be different from the JPEG.
